# Ordinary kriging is not working in QGIS 3.20 & SAGA-7.2.0

Tags: qgis, r, saga, kriging

I am using below data for making kriging interpolation.

```
structure(list(Serial = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 24L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 36L, 37L, 
43L, 44L, 46L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 58L, 59L), Station = c("NDDZ003", 
"NDDZ004", "NDDZ007", "NDDZ010", "NDDZ011", "NDDZ012", "NDDZ013", 
"NDDZ016", "NDDZ019", "NDDZ022", "NDDZ026", "NDDZ027", "NDDZ028", 
"NDDZ 031", "NDDZ034", "NDDZ035", "NDDZ041", "NDDZ046", "NDDZ048", 
"NDDZ050", "NDDZ055", "NDDZ058", "NDDZ065", "NDDZ066", "NDDZ068", 
"NDDZ072", "NDDZ073", "NDDZ074", "NDDZ082", "NDDZ085"), Longitude = c(119.6390058, 
119.598935, 119.9208017, 119.6457175, 119.5995872, 119.9621681, 
119.8415156, 119.6411364, 119.9633347, 119.6554394, 119.6042617, 
119.9721892, 119.8043606, 119.8156314, 119.8109757, 119.9013884, 
120.1667206, 120.0796901, 119.7829741, 119.9602213, 119.7401038, 
120.1113902, 119.7060803, 120.1239972, 119.7798066, 120.0968136, 
119.7086703, 119.7827459, 120.0621476, 120.1281223), Latitude = c(26.61166167, 
26.61266389, 26.64317889, 26.64771528, 26.64152194, 26.67770639, 
26.68016278, 26.68405639, 26.71346278, 26.71887583, 26.75296111, 
26.78070917, 26.78824, 26.48095232, 26.51638163, 26.53300528, 
26.54343039, 26.56656159, 26.59238665, 26.6023812, 26.62635719, 
26.64614884, 26.70021888, 26.70684282, 26.72669529, 26.75513142, 
26.77262578, 26.7665767, 26.6238606, 26.809988), MPs = c(17.85331969, 
52.10050251, 196.4787112, 21.07527437, 35.32763533, 91.0152754, 
142.260457, 120.0175822, 84.64602571, 47.67692504, 260.7229319, 
29.143898, 151.1290121, 101.1310963, 126.7889088, 85.74767297, 
153.5234525, 51.35979247, 42.82041038, 214.4548942, 96.9063435, 
155.5864259, 46.01889546, 97.50099786, 78.36325034, 161.375366, 
99.76091135, 59.82528502, 98.7524581, 110.3141717)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

While applying kriging the screen showed total black. can any one solve this?
The screen look liked that after interpolation
[image]

At first i did this in the picture , also I choose `output extent` as `draw canvas`
[image]

but after that I did in below two picture
[image]
[image]

Now I don't know where the problem is. At first my SAGA version was 7.9, some friend suggested me to install older version of SAGA (7.2), but it is also same as 7.9.

Comment: Does anything happen if you change the symbology for the raster?

Comment: no sir, nothing happened, i also tried to install smart map plugin, it saying classfactory() error